# Definition - Logarithmic Zeros and Algebraic Vector Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, definition

In Algebraic Geometry, what is the difference between an algebraic vector field and a derivation (are they completely different or synonymous)?

What does it mean to say an algebraic vector field has logarithmic zeros/poles on a subvariety?

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you gave some context. Where did you find the terminology "algebraic vector field"?

Comment: http://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9202007v1.pdf